# undefined params and session hashes in before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

Does anybody know why, when using `ruby-debug` by calling `debugger` in a method called as a `before_filter`, the `params` and `session` hashes are not defined?

```
class MyExampleController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :test_hashes

  def test_hashes
    pp session    
    pp params   #both work as expected..

    debugger #calling the debug console
  end

  def index
    #whatever..
  end

end

#the rdb console
(rdb:5) pp params
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<ActionController::Filters::BeforeFilter:0x3eafda0>
(rdb:5) pp session
NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method 'session' for #<ActionController::Filters::BeforeFilter:0x3eafda0>
```

Is this normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a b.s. line after the call to debugger and see what happens.

Comment: a numeric literal like 1 or something like that. b.s. as in bullshit.

Comment: I thought you were referring to that BS, but I couldn't see how could that do any good. :)  But I did try it and it worked! I can't believe it! How come?! Do you have a reasonable explanation? Is this a bug?

Comment: It seems to break on the line after 'debugger'. When you put 'debugger' at the end of a method it breaks somewhere up the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it doesn't work, but you can get to the variables through controller.params and controller.session